# Reading xml as it is from file system

Tags: xml, node.js

I have xml file stored in file system . I want read  xml file as it is without parsing and put it on the browser form node.js program. I have tried following code for that :

```
        var filePath="./hotel.xml";
    var fileContent=fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    console.log(fileContent);
```

But it is giving me the strange outputs. please someone help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issue by using :

```
        fs.readFile('./hotel.xml', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if(err) 
        {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        res.send(data);
    });
```